# Change a Specific Color in an ImageIcon

Tags: java

I am working with 24x24 pixel icons.  And I would like to be able to change a specific color within this icon to a different color.  For example turn the white areas to red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of an API method that does that. And by default, `Images` are not writable. However, if you have a [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), you could do it like this:

```
public void changeColor(BufferedImage img, Color old, Color new) {
    final int oldRGB = old.getRGB();
    final int newRGB = new.getRGB();
    for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
            if (img.getRGB(x, y) == oldRGB)
                img.setRGB(x, y, newRGB);
        }
    }
}
```

This is not the most efficient way to do it (it's possible to fetch RGB data into an array instead of one pixel at a time), but for 24x24 images it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [BufferedImage](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). Take a look at the Java [Image I/O documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/index.html).